# How to implement files?

Tags: perl, file

Suppose I have some records in a file:

```
ID Name Age Salary Phone
1  Ram  60  100   123456789000
2  tam  30  200   7436674776
3  sam  20  300   3734837837
4  kim  30  400   2
```

How to display details of all people who have no valid phone number?

This is what I have done:

```
open(f, <Users);
my @col = map { (split)[4] } split /\n/, f; # Phone numbers are stored in an array

foreach my $i ( @col ) {

    if ( grep -v /[[:digit:]]{10}/, @col ) {

        print "grep success\n";
        print "$i";
    }
}
```

But I am getting many errors.

I have other questions,  like how to I modify salary by 15% if the person has an experience > 20 years?

Comment: What is a valid phone number? Just 10 digits and no separators? Based on the data you’ve provided, it’s impossible to know how much experience someone has—we only have their ages!

Comment: This code is severely broken and doesn’t even compile.

Comment: “Please enlighten me with the correct syntax...” No, that’s **your** job. https://www.perl.org/learn.html

Comment: Add `use warnings; use strict;` to your code and then learn about how to read through a file correctly https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are writing code by just guessing at syntax. And that's unlikely to work out well unless you get **very** lucky (and most of us just aren't that lucky).

I suggest that you take a step back and find [a good resource that can teach you the basics](https://learn.perl.org/) of Perl syntax - as you're clearly having trouble with it currently.

The first two errors in your existing code are caused by simple typos in the code. You open your file with this code:

```
open(f, <Users);
```

But the file name and the open mode need to be in a quoted string.

```
open(f, '<Users');
```

However, it's generally accepted as good practice to a) use a lexical variable as your file handle.

```
open(my $f, '<Users');
```

b) Have the open mode and file name as separate arguments to `open()`.

```
open(my $f, '<', 'Users');
```

And c) check the return value from `open()` and take appropriate action.

```
open(my $f, '<', 'Users') or die "Cannot open 'Users': $!\n";
```

Secondly, you try to read from your filehandle by just using its name.

```
... split /\n/, f;
```

But you need to use the file input operator (`< ... >`) to read data from a filehandle.

```
... split /\n/, <f>;
```

And if you use my advice and switch to using a lexical variable for a filehandle.

```
... split /\n/, <$f>;
```

I highly recommend that you get into the habit of adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to all of your Perl code - and then understand and fix all of the problems they reveal.